# numpy array not yielding desired results

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a 2-D array with 
    len(counter) 
number of rows and 
    len(t) 
number of columns like so

```
del_A_chain = np.empty([len(counter),len(t)],order='C')
del_phi_chain = np.empty([len(counter),len(t)],order='C')
```

However after I insert the first row I am not printing my desired results.

```
del_A_chain
[-1.86208333 -0.39896537  1.76347579 ...,  0.          0.             0.        ]
del_phi_chain
[ 0.3645103  -0.06868272  0.28731659 ...,  0.          0.          0.        ]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "altercations_add.py", line 194, in <module>
chi_old = chi_2(A_chain[l-1],b_chain[l-1],phi_chain[l-1],A_obs_chain[l-  1],b_obs_chain[l-1],phi_obs_chain[l-1],del_A_chain[l-1][:],del_phi_chain[l- 1][:])
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Am I initializing them wrong? I have tried putting parentheses instead of brackets in the initialization.

Comment: Please update your question by showing how you insert values to arrays and what `counter` and `t`

Comment: `del_A_chain` is initialized as a 2d array, but the print value is a 1d.  ANd error suggests it is that as well.  They don't match.  Also forget the `[:]`.  It's not helping, even the array as 2d.